# Build pjsip for android with video support

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, pjsip, libyuv

Not sure if PJSIP for android support video now(v2.3).

I've built openh264v1.0.0 & libyuv(from google code) and install v4l2, sdl2 with apt-get.

```
 $ sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
 $ sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
 $ sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
 $ sudo apt-get install nasm
```

Here's my cmd:

```
$ ./configure-android --with-libyuv=/usr/local/lib --with-openh264=/usr/local/lib
```

But the log still says v4l2, sdl2, openh264, libyuv disabled...

```
...
Checking if SDL is disabled... yes
Checking if ffmpeg is disabled... yes
checking for v4l2_open in -lv4l2... no
Using OpenH264 prefix... yes
checking OpenH264 availability... failed
Using libyuv prefix... yes
checking for I420Scale in -lyuv... no
...
```

Also comparing android build doc with ios bulid doc, I find in android it doesn't mention thing about video. Is pjsip for android not support video for now like [this](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/milestone/release-2.4) said?

Comment: hi Robert : am also facing same issue in IOS (checking for I420Scale in -lyuv... no). did u solve ur issue ?

Comment: found any solution? I am getting this -> Using OpenH264 prefix... yes  as  Using OpenH264 prefix... no @Robert